Как перебрать цифры от 0 до 10 с помощью цикла for, чтобы получился результат 10_0_9_1_8_2_7_3_6_4_5_5_4_6_3_7_2_8_1_9_0_10
Необходимо с помощью цикла for, выстроить последовательность цифр 10_0_9_1_8_2_7_3_6_4_5_5_4_6_3_7_2_8_1_9_0_10
let btn15 = document.querySelector('.b-15');
let out15 = document.querySelector('.out-15');

function f15(){
    out15.innerHTML = '';
    for(let i = 10; i >= 0; i--){
        out15.innerHTML += i + '_'; 

    for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
            out15.innerHTML += i + '_'; 

        };
    };
};
f15();


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Вложенный цикл тут не нужен (и даже противопоказан), можно сделать на одном цикле, используя разность.

Например, так:


const array = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
  array.push(10 - i);
  array.push(i);
}
console.log(array.join('_'));




А yield в JS нет, интересно? )

@CrazyElf, конечно, есть :) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

@CrazyElf, а как он тут поможет?

@Grundy Ну, я привык в подобных задачах числа через yield/yield return выдавать. Но если чисел немного, да и в JS так вообще принято, то массив, конечно, норм.

@Grundy Ой, только тут это вообще другое, чем в других языках что ли ))  Это не генератор, а наоборот что ли...

@CrazyElf, yield в Javascript передаёт данные в обоих направлениях. В итератор можно передавать значения. Но основное назначение и функциональность такие же как в Питоне. И в Питоне обратную передачу данных тоже можно сделать: итератор и тело цикла будут работать как полноценные сопрограммы.

Спасибо за помощь
